# How to make Spring see only the last path variable added to url?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I would like to specify get request only for `/show-owner/{id}`, but every time there is another path added to URL I get 404 not found error and I have to give full path to make it work.
What is the best approach in such cases ?

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"/show-owner/{id}", "/show-item/show-owner/{id}",
            "/show-user/user-items-table/show-item/show-owner/{id}",
            "/show-user/user-items-table/show-item/show-owner/user-items-table/{id}",
    "/show-owner/user-items-table/show-item/show-owner/{id}",
    "/user-items-table/show-item/show-owner/{id}"})
    public ModelAndView displayOwnerByItemId(@PathVariable String id) {
        try {
            UserDto user = userDtoMapper.toDto(itemService.getItemById(id).getOwner());

            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("show-user");
            mav.addObject("user", user);
            return mav;
        } catch (ItemNotFound e) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/items");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong path URL in your form or links from where you are calling the @GetMapping("/show-owner/{id}"). Can you show me your HTML code from where you are calling the URL /show-owner/{id}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using the wrong url in your HTML form
for example...

```
<form action="show-owner/{id}">
```

be sure your URL is correct. It should be

```
<form action="/show-owner/{id}">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do one thing if you want just the last  id from the path variable. You will be getting the ids in comma separated string. So the simplest solution will be to split the string based on the comma and get the value of last index like this.

```
String k[] = id.split(",");
System.out.println(k[k.length-1]);//just to check whether u are getting the last id value or not
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I don't want to get the ID. I just don't want to specify url every time it changed and make my getter works with single mapping value like this. @GetMapping("/show-owner/{id}")

Comment: Okay, then I will edit my answer for that